# dual boot password loss problems

Tags: ubuntu, windows-vista

I have a dell D630 which has two operating systems installed on it. Windows vista and Ubuntu. the problem is that i have forgotten the root password to the ubuntu os. my main problem is that i cannot figure out how to reset the password. note i have access to the guest account. however upon booting the device i am presented with  windows boot manager. it asks me to select a device to boot to. when i select to boot to ubuntu it boots ubuntu fine. however i canot figure out how to edit ubuntu's boot options

Comment: Do you get a grub[2] prompt after selecting Ubuntu in the windows boot manager? It is it there, can you add 'single' to the boot options to boot in single user mode? If that does not work, grab a liveCD, boot it and mount the Ubuntu root partition. Then continue with chroot and password.

Comment: If I recall correctly, Ubuntu's root account is not able to log in.  Is that maybe the issue you're facing?

Comment: ok were can i get a live cd?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD

Answer (score 1):

You can download a live CD and boot from that. That will give you access to to the files on the harddisk, including the part which contains your root password.

Since you use Ubunto the LiveCD you are most familiar with might be [this one](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD).

That way you can get a root shell on your system. However any password changes you make will be made to the root of the liveCD and not to the partition on the disk. To change this we will use chroot to change our shell to a new root. (chroot stands for change-root).

Mount the old root filesystem using command like these.
(Adjust fstype and partition to match your system)

`mkdir /mnt/olddisk`
`mount -t *ext2* /dev/sdaX /mnt/olddisk`

Then change your root to match the root of the old disk:
`chroot /mnt/olddisk`.

And change the password(s):
`passwd root`